# ModelForm can't see my attributes-fields, form ProfileForm needs update

Tags: python, django, django-shop

I was doing django eshop from the tutorials and everything was going well until everything crashed when I tried to make Cabinet in Users:

here is My views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from .forms import RegisterForm
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate , login as django_login , logout as django_logout
    from .models import Profile
    from .forms import ProfileForm
    
    def cabinet(request):
    django_user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=django_user)
    context = {
        'form': ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    }
    return render(request, 'users/cabinet/main.html', context)
```

My main.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}

     <h1>Welcome {{ request.user.username }}!</h1>

      <form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
         <div>
            <label for="">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ request.user.first_name }}">
         </div>

         <div>
            <label for="">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{ request.user.last_name }}">
         </div>

         <div>
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
         </div>

        {{ form }}

         <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </form>

     {% endblock content %}
```

My models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User




    class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, null=True)
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=4)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} Rate: {}'.format(self.user.username, self.rate)
```

and My forms.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from .models import Profile

     class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
        first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=225, required=False)
        second_name = forms.CharField(max_length=225, required=False)
        email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, required=False)

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Custom save!!')
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        django_user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],
            first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            last_name=self.cleaned_data['second_name'],
            email=self.cleaned_data['email']
        )

        Profile.objects.create(user=django_user)
        return django_user


     class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
         class Meta:
          model = Profile
          fields = '__all__'
```

I think the problem in [class ProfileForm] since I get error -.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form Prof
ileForm needs updating.

But i did mention Fields! why it doesn't work? :(

Comment: Why do you have `class Meta` inside `class ProfileForm`?  The `fields` entry is part of `Meta` here, not `ProfileForm`.

Comment: so how can i fix it? I've been shown in this way and it worked with meta class inside ProfileForm class. but not in my project(

Comment: Yes, I see now, you're right.  The indentation in your code snippets is not correct.  It's probably just a cut-and-paste problem, but can you check that?

Comment: Here it looks like I have an indentation problem, however, in the project, everything is written as it should be. At least pycharm must show if there is some. but it doesn't. Also when I type Meta class it supposed to give me automatically hint what to write, but again it doesn't. what exactly I can check?

Comment: If you type `ProfileForm.Meta` does it give you suggestions?

Comment: when i type class Meta as a subclass of ProfileForm it doesn't give me suggestions (